# Web worker fetching data

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have webworker like below:

```
class FetchWorker {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.ids = [];
        this.timer = 1;
    }

    start() {
        this.fetchData();
    }

    addIds(ids) {
        this.ids.push(...ids);
    }

    sendData(method, data){
        self.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
            method,
            data
        }))
    }

    fetchData() {
        this.timer *= 2;
        console.log(this.id,') ### this', this);
        console.log(this.id,') ### ids', this.ids);
        console.log(this.id,') ### FetchData', this.ids.length, this.timer);
        console.log(this.id,') ######');

        if(!this.ids.length) {
            setTimeout(this.fetchData, this.timer);
            return;
        }

        console.log(this.id, ')FETCHED ...');

        this.sendData('webworker:fetchedAds', this.ids);
        this.sendData('webworker:timer', this.timer);

        setTimeout(this.fetchData, this.timer);
    }
}

const id = Number.parseInt((Math.random() * 100) + '');

console.log('self', self);

const worker = new FetchWorker(id);

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
    const {method, data} = message;

    if (method === 'webworker:addids') {
        worker.addIds(data);
    }

    if (method === 'webworker:startFetching'){
        worker.start();
    }
});
```

I am creating this worker and send to him message with ids and with start command, but i get error in fetchData method when i try to write length of ids Array to console, error is *Cannot read property length of undefined*,

I checked it and this in my fetchData method pointing to DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope instead of FetchWorker class, it's a bit confused for me because i don't know why this doesn't exists in class method

Comment: fixed, it was my mistake its not about this error

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by bind this to fetchData in setTimeouts and it is look like:

```
setTimeout(this.fetchData.bind(this), this.timer * 1000);
```

I don't know why i had to do that

Comment: You had to do that because `this` in JavaScript is set when the function is called, not when the function is defined. So `setTimeout(this.fetchData, this.timer);` does the equivalent of `functionToRunLater = this.fetchData` and then `functionToRunLater()`. That type of call `functionToRunLater()` sets the `this` value to the global object, unlike `foo.functionToRunLater()` which would set `this` to `foo`. When you do `.bind(this)`, it force the function to use the value of `this` at the moment you write `.bind(this)`, which is the correct value in your case.

Comment: For more information, read http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/.

Comment: Oh i get it, i can did setTimeout(()=>this.fetchData, 1) to avoid it, so thank you i don't think after 12 hours of work